# Cloudd quit unexpectedly

Tags: icloud

Ever since I upgraded to Yosemite, I have been experiencing `cloudd quit unexpectedly` bug reports popping up at front very very often.

The issue is :

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Error opening db at /Users/peter/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata: <CKError 0x7f8bc1419590: "Internal Error" (1)> (14/0x000e/unable to open database file)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
abort() called


Application Specific Backtrace 1:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88a6464c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff89b036de objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff88a644fd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   CloudKit                            0x00007fff83448a47 -[CKSQLite raise:] + 516
4   CloudKit                            0x00007fff834483b6 -[CKSQLite open] + 122
5   CloudKitDaemon                      0x000000010b523481 -[CKDMetadataCache init] + 199
6   CloudKitDaemon                      0x000000010b5233a0 __31+[CKDMetadataCache sharedCache]_block_invoke + 41
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff88e1fc13 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff88e1fb26 dispatch_once_f + 117
9   CloudKitDaemon                      0x000000010b523375 +[CKDMetadataCache sharedCache] + 46
10  cloudd                              0x000000010b37e541 cloudd + 5441
11  cloudd                              0x000000010b37e0e0 cloudd + 4320
12  cloudd                              0x000000010b37eace cloudd + 6862
13  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff85ebf5c9 start + 1
```

I do not know if this is relevant, but during 10.9 to 10.10 (yosemite) upgrade, I was asked to log in with my apple ID. I was connected to a WIFI provider (but not logged in) so I wasn't able to log in. The update did continue. On the first session I opened, iCloud kept crashing. I had a really hard time disabling iCloud drive.

Comment: is your WiFi connection stable?

Answer (score 1):

The exception message says:

`Error opening db at /Users/peter/Library/Caches/CloudKit/CloudKitMetadata`

Make sure that `cloudd` has permissions to write in that directory.
If the directories permissions are fine, maybe the db was corrupted during the update. Try to move the file somewhere else, it's possible `cloudd` will recreate it if it doesn't see it.

Comment: It is not a permission issue, but rather a sandbox issue.

Comment: It might not be a permission issue but nowhere in the stack trace I see any mention of sandboxd. Why do you say it's a sandbox issue ?

Comment: You wouldn't see it in the stack. But I see the sandbox denying the access in the log. Plus, I tried giving unix + ACL permissions to everyone. Doesn't work. I tried copying a working database there (that I created using an other user on the MAC) : this time, I get a write error (the DB appears to be readonly). The sandbox is refusing write access to cloudd.

Comment: I guess you're right @PeterG. I've a few problems too since Yosemite, please post a solution if you find one.

Comment: I have a solution, but you won't like it. 1: Sign out of icloud. 2. Kill the user account on the computer. 3. Re-create it as admin. 4. Sign in icloud.  5. switch the account to regular user if you wish and fix perms. 6. Be certain not to have any sym links / alias in the path to your libary folder.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue with Yosemite. iMac14,2 / 3.5GHz Intel Quad Core i7/ 8G RAM / OSX10.10 / 3TB Fusion HD

cloudd.app continued to quit and I would get notifications of its quit.

Boot into SafeMode.
Rebooted back into my adm. account.
I get no more cloudd.app quits.

Comment: Forget the safeboot mode. the issue still remains.

Comment: If this doesn't solve the problem, please delete it. It will continue to attract down votes for being an entirely wrong answer to the question asked.